# WordPress - JS and PHP in a PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I would like to include the following code in my functions.php file in WordPress, but am stuck getting the correct format, it's broken at present.

This is the code I have currently -

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if (jQuery('body.default, body.alternative').length) {
               twitterFetcher.fetch('<?php echo $redux_demo['divider-twitter-id']; ?>', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
        };
     });
</script>
```

Many thanks for any tips

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I basically have a script called twitter fetcher which displays your latest tweet. It takes your twitter ID and outputs your latest tweet on the page. the echo statement is from my theme options panel, where a user can input their twitter id.

Comment: Or is it possible to echo the php as a variable in a js file? Not sure how?

Comment: Yes, you can. instead of naming the file `script.js`, you can name it `script.php`, and include it like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.php"></script>` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<?php echo $redux_demo["divider-twitter-id"]; ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php echo $redux_demo['divider-twitter-id']; ?>
```

You need to wrap `divider-twitter-id` in double quotes, not single quote here.

Comment: Hi, Even with that the code is still not valid in the .php file? The script tags are black and blue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of 'adding js into a PHP file', You need to echo it:

```
<?php
 echo "<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     if (jQuery('body.default, body.alternative').length) {
        twitterFetcher.fetch('" . $redux_demo['divider-twitter-id'] . "', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
    };
  });
 </script>";
?>
```

But to accomplish what you're trying to do, put in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');

function theme_scripts() {
  if (!is_admin()) {  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twitter-fetcher',  THEME_URL . '/js/twitter-fetcher.php?twitterId=' . $redux_demo['divider-twitter-id']);
  }
}
```

Then in in `wp-content/theme/js/twitter-fetcher.php`,

```
<?php
// Sets the proper content type for javascript
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     if (jQuery('body.default, body.alternative').length) {
        twitterFetcher.fetch('<?php $_GET['twitterId']; ?>', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
   };
});
```

Comment: Hi Cooper,
Can I drop this into my functions.php file?

thanks

Comment: You should wrap it around a function and drop it inside that, and call the function in the front end. If you drop it in the function.php file you will get a headers already sent fatal error.

Comment: I tried this in functions.php, which totally broke things :(

    function twitter_fetcher() {
    echo "<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     if (jQuery('body.default, body.alternative').length) {
        twitterFetcher.fetch('" . $redux_demo['divider-twitter-id'] . "', 'twitter-fetcher-tweet', 1, true, false);
    };
  });
     </script>";
      }

Comment: Updated to reflect what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks Cooper, I will try this. Quick question is this a case where I could use the wp_localize_script function? I've never actually tried using it before?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Cooper, I'm currently getting - Undefined variable: redux_demo in my functions.php?

Comment: I've no idea what `redux_demo` is supposed to be, but the reason that's happening is because the `$redux_demo` variable is not defined in `functions.php`. You need to make sure it's defined before this code is ran.

Comment: Have now set global variable. Used enqueue code above in functions.php, and then the javascript code into twitter-fetcher.php, but I get nothing outputting?